# Prometheus scrapes particular microservice metrics from several containers in Docker Swarm

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm using `Grafana` and `Prometheus` in a `Docker swarm` environment. I've set up `docker-compose.yml` and `prometheus.yml` to scrape metrics from node-exporter and microservices.

My question is how to scrape metrics from microservice, when it is running over multiple containers.

When I run grafana, I only see the output from one container, not from all of them.

```
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

networks:
  monitoring:

volumes:
  #prometheus_data: {}
  prometheus_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=pvevm26,rw
      device: :/srv/nexusshare-mnt/metrics/prometheus_data/
  grafana_data: {}
configs:
  metrics_prometheus_v1.conf:
    external: true
  metrics_grafana_ini_v1.conf:
    external: true

services:
#####################################################
# Prometheus
#####################################################
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    configs:
      - source: metrics_prometheus_v1.conf
        target: /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    volumes:
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.no-lockfile'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Hostname of the node!
          - node.role == worker
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 1G
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10M"
        max-file: "1"
    networks:
      - monitoring
#####################################################
# Node-exporter
# For each node a separate service need to be added
#####################################################
  docker-s1-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9101:9100
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Hostname of the node!
          - node.hostname == Docker-s1
          - node.platform.os == linux
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 128M
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10M"
        max-file: "1"
    networks:
      - monitoring
  
  docker-s2-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9102:9100
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Hostname of the node!
          - node.hostname == Docker-s2
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 128M
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10M"
        max-file: "1"
    networks:
      - monitoring
  
  docker-s3-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9103:9100
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Hostname of the node!
          - node.hostname == Docker-s3
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 128M
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10M"
        max-file: "1"
    networks:
      - monitoring

  docker-s4-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9104:9100
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Hostname of the node!
          - node.hostname == Docker-s4
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 128M
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10M"
        max-file: "1"
    networks:
      - monitoring
  
  docker-s5-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9105:9100
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Hostname of the node!
          - node.hostname == Docker-s5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 128M
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10M"
        max-file: "1"
    networks:
      - monitoring

  docker-s6-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    volumes:
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
    command:
      - '--path.procfs=/host/proc' 
      - '--path.sysfs=/host/sys'
      - --collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points
      - "^/(sys|proc|dev|host|etc|rootfs/var/lib/docker/containers|rootfs/var/lib/docker/overlay2|rootfs/run/docker/netns|rootfs/var/lib/docker/aufs)($$|/)"
    ports:
      - 9106:9100
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        constraints:
          # Hostname of the node!
          - node.hostname == Docker-s6
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 128M
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10M"
        max-file: "1"
    networks:
      - monitoring
#####################################################
# The Grafana
#####################################################
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    # image: grafana/grafana:8.2.6
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    configs:
      - source: metrics_grafana_ini_v1.conf
        target: /etc/grafana/grafana.ini
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '2'
          memory: 1G
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10M"
        max-file: "1"
    networks:
      - monitoring
```

```
prometheus.yml
global:
- job_name: 'my-service-job'
  dns_sd_configs:
   - names: ['tasks.my-service-name']
     scrape_interval: 15s
     type: 'A'
     port: 80
```

---

**UPDATE:**
I found out that I should use dns_sd_config inside prometheus.yml
like [here:](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/scraping-docker-swarm-service-instances-with-prometheus/)
But I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will probably want is an instance of Prometheus within the swarm to scrape the individual services (rather then the load balanced endpoints) and then federate that data out to the main Prometheus set up.

[This blog post](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/scraping-docker-swarm-service-instances-with-prometheus/) has a pretty good explanation on what to do.